# How to get the file's name and content in the terminal, for all files in a directory

Tags: files, terminal

Assume I have unknown number of files in a directory. I want to get the contents inside each file along with the file-name as in below example.

file1 "content in file one"
file2 "content in file two"
file3 "content in file three"
.......    .......................
filen  "content in file n"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assume the [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) are textual, and not too big (e.g. less than 10000 lines).

Then you might try using [head(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) (maybe as `head -vn -0 file*` with GNU head) like this

```
head -10000 file1 file2 file3
```

Remember that some files are binary, that is they contain something else than text. For example, a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump), an [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database file, a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) image, an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file, or even some [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) file created with LibreOffice. On such files, using `head` (or [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)) don't give nice results, because they are not [text files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) but contain a sequence of almost arbitrary bytes.

You might be also interested by the [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command. It tries to guess what is the content type of a given file. Read also about [media types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) (or MIME types)

Remember that on Unix like system a file is actually an [i-node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) and could have *several* names (see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html), [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html), [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) for more). The name of a file don't means much. A file basically is a sequence of bytes with some way to name it. How that sequence is used depends upon the program accessing the file.

You could be interested by `xdg-open` which tries to show, in a graphical manner, various kind of files (it is adapting to the content of those files).

Read also about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). Maybe learn about the `for` builtin of your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). Read about `bash` [looping constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html).

Comment: With GNU head, `-n -0` for all lines

Comment: With GNU `head`, better with `head -vn -0 file*`, so the header is displayed even if there's only one file.

Comment: @HirSK: I don't have that much time to teach you Linux command line. Get a book about it. BTW Linux has directories (not folders). Folders are just the thing you see in your GUI

Answer (score 3):

For that specific output format, you can do:

```
awk '{print substr(FILENAME, 3)" \""$0"\" "}' ./file*
```

Which would print the name of the file followed by the content of the line inside quotes for each line of the file.

We add a `./` prefix which we strip with `substr()` to work around the problem that `awk` considers arguments like `filex=y.txt` as a variable assignment instead of a file name.

If the files already contain `"` characters and you want to display them as `\"` (and `\` as `\\` to remove ambiguities):

```
awk '{gsub(/[\\"]/, "\\\\&"); print substr(FILENAME, 3)" \""$0"\" "}' ./file*
```

(that doesn't address `"` in the file name itself).

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```
for f1 in *; do echo -n "$f1"" "\"; cat "$f1"; echo "\""; done
```

It loops through all files in the directory, then, for each file shows its name followed by its contents in quotation marks.