view a bunch of text files in the terminal
I've got a bunch of text files and pdfs in a directory.
If I enter
evince *.pdf

..all the pdfs open up in separate windows, I do this quite often.
When I enter
cat *.txt

..was pleasantly surprised to see it shows all the text files in the terminal. Problem is it has them all just laid end to end you can't really tell where one ends and the next one begins or which one you're looking at as you scroll.
Is there an improvement to this cat command whereby it will give the name of the file in the terminal before dumping its contents? That's the main point, but perhaps a line or blank space after the text file ended so you would know it had ended would also be nice to have.
Otherwise, a better terminal command than cat which accomplishes this.

Just found a suitable answer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513132/188451
head -10000 *.txt

That does a nice job printing the file names. Does not leave any space after and the files must not be too long which they are not.
